Unable to set timestamp on Android MediaCodec Image object from native c++ code
I have an created a queue to store images from ImageReader in cpp.
while copying the queued items to the Image object from MediaCodec.getInputImage(index) method I'm facing an issue where the byte buffers are successfully copied but the timestamp is not set.
there are no errors thrown and so I'm very confused.
The queue holds objects of the following class.
class YUV420 {
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    **long long timestampUs;**
    std::vector<YUVImagePlane> planes;

    YUV420(int width, int height, long long timestampUs)
            : width(width), height(height), timestampUs(timestampUs) {
        // Pre-allocate planes for Y, U, and V
        planes.emplace_back(width * height, 1, width);  // Y plane
        planes.emplace_back(width * height / 2, 2, width);  // U plane
        planes.emplace_back(width * height / 2, 2, width);  // V plane
    }

....

The relevant code for the copy function is:
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_YuvUtils_copyToImage2(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */,
        jobject image  // The MediaCodec Image object from Kotlin)
) {
...
 YUV420 &yuvFrame = yuvQueue.dequeue();
 jclass imageClass = env->GetObjectClass(image);

 // Get the setTimestamp method ID
    jmethodID setTimestampMethodID = env->GetMethodID(imageClass, "setTimestamp", "(J)V");
    if (setTimestampMethodID == nullptr) {
        LOGE("setTimestamp method not found in Image class.");
        env->DeleteLocalRef(imageClass);
        return;
    }

    // Call the setTimestamp method
    env->CallVoidMethod(image, setTimestampMethodID, static_cast<jlong>(yuvFrame.timestampUs));

    // Check for exceptions
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();  // Print the exception to the log
        env->ExceptionClear();      // Clear the exception so the JNI call can proceed
        LOGE("Exception occurred while setting timestamp.");
    } else {
        LOGI("Timestamp set to %lld", yuvFrame.timestampUs);
    }

    // Verify the value by getting the current timestamp from the Image object
    jmethodID getTimestampMethodID = env->GetMethodID(imageClass, "getTimestamp", "()J");
    if (getTimestampMethodID == nullptr) {
        LOGE("getTimestamp method not found in Image class.");
    } else {
        jlong retrievedTimestamp = env->CallLongMethod(image, getTimestampMethodID);
        if (retrievedTimestamp == static_cast<jlong>(yuvFrame.timestampUs)) {
            LOGI("Timestamp verification succeeded.");
        } else {
            LOGE("Timestamp verification failed. Expected: %lld, but got: %lld",
                 yuvFrame.timestampUs, retrievedTimestamp);
        }
    }

//  planes will be copied below.... that part is working 

}

a sample output for this code's log is as follows:
Timestamp set to 608659736453232
Timestamp verification failed. Expected: 608659736453232, but got: 0
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

NOTE: I know that I can just return the timestamp from the JNI function to pass it on as PTS in MediaCodec. But my question is why I'm not able to use the setter here.

What happens if instead of setting the timestamp from the yuv image, you set the timestamp obtained from codec itself incremented by let's say 1-2 us? That might validate the timestamp itself and help isolate the issue.

Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly, but when I do getTimestamp on the image object returned by getInputImage from the mediaCodec the time stamp is always 0.
Is there another timestamp I can obtain from the MediaCodec?

getInputImage gives a buffer in which we need to write the image/frame data.
Rest would be up to queueInputBuffer :)

Sorry I too misunderstood the question earlier :D
I've posted the answer (all code in java).
Let me know if you have any questions.
Also, my opinion would be to keep all this code in Java/Kotlin.
Critical code can be moved to native (C/C++).
Eg. frame data transfer could be moved.

getInputBuffer(index) returns a writable buffer that we use to write the frame data into.
And when ready, we need to queue it to the Encoder MediaCodec for encoding using queueInputBuffer which would need buffer metadata, timestamp and frame flags.
Here is the complete (Java) version for your info:
Obtain the input buffer:
Call getInputBuffer(index) to obtain a writable buffer from the codec. You will write the raw frame data (e.g., YUV data) into this buffer for encoding.
ByteBuffer inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
if (inputBuffer != null) {
    // Clear the buffer
    inputBuffer.clear();
    // Write frame data into the input buffer
    inputBuffer.put(frameData);
}

Queue the input buffer:
After writing the frame data, you need to queue the buffer using queueInputBuffer. You'll also provide metadata such as the buffer index, offset, size of the frame data, timestamp, and flags.
codec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, frameData.length, presentationTimeUs, flags);


index: The index of the input buffer
0: Offset in the buffer where
data begins (usually 0).
frameData.length: Size of the frame data in
the buffer.
presentationTimeUs: The presentation timestamp in
microseconds. It helps in ordering frames during playback.
flags: Frame-specific flags like BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM or
BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME

End of Stream flag
You'll also need to send an End of stream frame.
codec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, frameData.length, presentationTimeUs, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);


Thanks @Sahil you comment was what I was looking for i.e. it getInputImage is mainly for passing in the Buffers only and the rest need to be passed in while queuing the input buffer.

I'm glad you got your answer.
